# Wireless network does not appear in Raspberry Pi 4B list of available networks

Tags: wifi, vnc

I am extremely new to Raspberry Pi and am having difficulty getting a 4B to connect to a wireless network.  What I have tried thus far is:

- Edited the `wpa_supplicant.conf` with `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and set the SSID and Password to the wireless network.
- I did a `sudo reboot`.

When I issue a `ifconfig wlan0`, the response does not contain an entry for `inet addr`.  Additionally the wireless network does not appear in the list of available wireless networks.

I also noticed that the name of or wireless network that I used as the SSID in `wpa_supplicant.conf` does not appear in the list of available networks.

I do have a VNC connection from my desktop to the Raspberry Pi 4B over a RJ45 patch cable. The machine that I am using to drive the Raspberry Pi 4B is connected to the wireless network.

The VNC connection works without any issue.

Could VNC be blocking the connection to the wireless network?

Do I need to make changes to any other config files on the Raspberry Pi 4B?

**New Info**
A new entry has appeared in the `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
Disabled = 1
```

Removing this does not re-enable the WiFi on the Raspberry Pi 4B. I have found some articles on-line that say this will happen after a number of unsuccessful logins.  I have not found anything that discusses how to re-enable WiFi after this occurs. I am at a loss - starting over from scratch...

Comment: Is the network 5Ghz only?  You may have to fiddle to get that to work.  Confirm it can't see the network manually with `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan |  grep SSID`.

Comment: Hi goldilocks, I can see 5G and 4G in the list of available wireless servers.  The command above did not list the wireless connection that I am trying to connect the Raspberry Pi 4B to.

Comment: *I can see 5G and 4G* are mobile not wifi - do you mean 5GHz and 2.4GHz?  Is it on 5Ghz or 2.4GHz, what security does the network run, what channel is it on, is the SSID hidden from view, what have you set the WiFi country code to?  Can you please edit your question with answers and possible show a copy of the wpa_supplicant file (password and SSID can be hidden - replace characters with an 'x' but leave line in).

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
Post the output of `ip a; ip r` into your question.